# Proving that If $A$ and $B$ are compact then $\operatorname{dist}(A,B) > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen this question on here before, but I have a different attempt at the proof for it. We are given that $A$ and $B$ are compact and that $\operatorname{dist}(A,B) = \inf\{\Vert x-y \Vert: x \in A, y \in B\}.$

Here is my attempt at it:

So since we have that $A$ and $B$ are compact, we have that by the Heine-Borel theorem that both $A$ and $B$ are closed and bounded. There is a theorem in my text that states that for $E \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and $E$ closed, then $E$ contains all of its limit points. So from this we have that there exists $x_k \in A$ which converges to $x$, and some $y_j \in B$ that converges to $y$. Now, by the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem, each convergent sequence, has a convergent subsequence, namely we have that $y_{j_t}$ converges to $y$ as $t$ goes to infinity, and similarly for $x_{k_p}$ converges to $x$ as $p$ goes to infinity. But from here I'm unsure where to finish. I feel as if the approximation theorem for infimum can be used here, but maybe not.

Comment: Here is how you start: Suppose $d(A,B)=0$ Then there exists $(x_n) \subset A$ and $(y_n) \subset B$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$.

Comment: is that the only way?

Comment: Your arguements do not make sense becasue you don't say what $x$ and $y$ are. You have to start the proof the way I suggsted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say it, but I assume we also know $A \cap B = \emptyset$.  Assume $A, B \subseteq X$.

Define $U_n= \{x \in X \mid d(x, A) \gt \frac 1n \}$.  Each $U_n$ is open and since $A$ is closed (we don't need $A$ compact), $\{ U_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ is an open cover of $X \setminus A$.

Since $A \cap B = \emptyset, \{U_n \cap B \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$ is an open cover of $B$.

$B$ is compact so this open cover must have a finite subcover, so for some $N \in \Bbb N, B \subseteq U_N$ and $\operatorname{dist}(A, B) \ge \frac 1N \gt 0$.

Comment: By chance can we just use the approximation theorem for infima at the very beginning to define a distinct sequence that converges to something?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the approximation theorem for infima."  But if you choose a sequence $b_n \in B \cap U_n$ and a sequence of "witnesses" $a_n$ (where each $A_n$ "witnesses" that $b_n \in U_n$), you'll get infinite sequences in $A$ and $B$ that have convergent subsequences necessarily converging to the same limit, contradicting that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof that RobertShore's. I also assume that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ otherwise the result is false. I also relax the hypothesis and just suppose that $B$ is closed.

Suppose $A$ is compact, $B$ is closed and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. Let $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = d(x,B)$. By the triangle inequality, $f$ is $1$-Lipchitz, and thus is continuous. As $A$ is compact and $f$ continuous, $f$ has a global minimum, say $m\geqslant 0$ attained at $x_0$. That is
\begin{align}
d(A,B) = f(x_0) = d(x_0,B) = m \geqslant 0
\end{align}
Suppose by contradiction that $m = 0$. Then as $B$ is closed, $x_0 \in B$, which is a contradiction because $A\cap B = \varnothing$.
Thus, $f(x_0) >0$ and $d(A,B)>0$.

Comment: Is it possible to do this proof using the approximation theorem for infima?

Comment: What are you calling approximation theorem for infima?

Comment: Well, it is defined as for some $a \in dist(A,B)$ that there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $inf\{||x-y||: x \in A, y \in B\} \leq a < \epsilon + inf\{||x-y||: x \in A, y \in B\}$

Comment: Oh right. Yes you can do that I guess. Using the function $f$ above show that in fact, this infimum is a minimum (because $A$ is compact). Using ony the fact that it is an infimum will not give a positive answer : for example, if $A$ and $B$ are only closed but non compact, the result is false, while you can still write things with the infimum.